# Retrieve a value from a request with content type application/json

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

I have the following script that is sending data to a controller in MVC:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/products/create',
    type: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        'name':'widget',
        'foo':'bar'
    })
});
```

My controller looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Product product)
{
    return Json(new {success = true});
}

public class Product 
{ 
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way I can get the "foo" variable in my controller action without

- modifying the model
- modifying the signature of the action

**If it was a regular form submission, I would have access to Request.Form["foo"], but this value is null since it was submitted via application/json.**

I want to be able to access this value from an Action Filter and that is why I don't want to modify the signature/model.

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to do almost exactly the same today and found this question with no answer. I also solved it with similar solution as Mark.

This works very well for me in asp.net MVC 4. Could maybe help someone else reading this question even if it is an old one.

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            string jsonPostData;
            using (var stream = Request.InputStream)
            {
                stream.Position = 0;
                using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    jsonPostData = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            var foo = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, object>>(jsonPostData)["foo"];

            return Json(new { success = true });
        }
```

The important part was to reset the position of the stream because it is already read by some MVC internal code or whatever.

Comment: while this works, the problem i faced was one i read the stream onAuthorize now the stream was empty so when the controller received the request body there was nothing in it.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to be able to access this value from an Action Filter and that
>   is why I don't want to modify the signature/model.

Accessing the value from the Action filter would be tricky without changing the signature of the method. The reason will be better understand from this [post](http://build.mt.gov/2012/2/14/requestinputstream%20and%20json%20model%20binding%20in%20aspnet%20mvc%203.aspx).

This code will work in an authorization filter or somewhere the code that runs before the model binding.

```
public class CustomFilter : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
  {
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
      var request = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;

      var body = request.InputStream;
      var encoding = request.ContentEncoding;
      var reader = new StreamReader(body, encoding);
      var json = reader.ReadToEnd();

      var ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();

      // you can read the json data from here
      var jsonDictionary = ser.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(json); 

      // i'm resetting the position back to 0, else the value of product in the action  
      // method will  be null.
      request.InputStream.Position = 0; 
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

Even if this 'foo' is not binded, it will be available in you action filter through :

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Current.Request.Params
```

Have a look into these collection if you see your parameter.

So yes just create your action filter and  don't change the signature it will works.

Just in case debug your filter to be sure where will be the value.

Lastly you need to have your values provider for json registered in your global.asax :

```
protected void Application_Start() 
{
  RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
  ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new JsonValueProviderFactory());
}
```

You parameter is wrong as well it need to be more like :

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/products/create',
    type: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        name:'widget',
        foo:'bar'
    })
});
```

without quote.

**Edit (to be more precise):**

your filter will contains these method

```
public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{

}
public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{

}
```

Comment: in the ActionFilter, all method have parameter "filterContext"

Comment: public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            
        }

Comment: You right, sorry. check my edit, this time it's good small mistake from me.

Comment: What is the purpose of a downvote other than to inform others that the answer is incorrect?

Comment: If that the case then you have an issue when your data parameter as it should always do key/value.Have you tried to remove the quote like this data: JSON.stringify({
        name:'widget',
        foo:'bar'
    }),

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Request.Params what do you see inside this ? Any interesting values ?

Comment: Even if i do as you said, i cant find "foo" in filterContext.HttpContext.Current.Request.Params