# Get Post request parameters in custom AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, authentication

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19050773/384554) to get request parameters from input stream. POST is using JSON in the request body. In my `onAuthorize` function which is overrride for `AuthorizeAttribute`. It does give me the request body parameters, but it empties out stream so controller does not receive any request parameters:

```
 public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream.Length() //17 here
        string jsonPostData;
        using (var stream = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream)
        {
            stream.Position = 0;
            using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
            {
                jsonPostData = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        filterContext.HttpContext.InputStream.Length() //0 here
        filterContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream.Position = 0; // still 0

  base.OnAuthorization(filterContext); //so when the request reaches controller its empty
}
```

I guess what i am essentially asking is how to reset input stream after reading it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed code to this and it started working

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream.Length() //17 here
        string jsonPostData;
        var stream = request.InputStream;
        var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream);
        jsonPostData = reader.ReadToEnd();
        filterContext.HttpContext.InputStream.Length() //17 here
        filterContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream.Position = 0; //17 here

  base.OnAuthorization(filterContext); //so when the request reaches controller its empty
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading the stream, you could reset its position at the beginning:

```
stream.Position = 0;
```

You already did this before start reading the stream, so try resetting it the same way after reading it.

Comment: Darin check out my edit on the code i posted above, seems its still not working

Comment: If you don't read the input stream in your authorize attribute, you are getting correct values in your controller?

Comment: yes, i need to read it because its part of authorize thats how I get account ids to authorize

Comment: Normally if you set the Position of the stream to 0, the controller should be able to receive the proper model.